# Read headers from java micornaut service in FIlter

Tags: java, filter, httpresponse, micronaut

I want to read the headers which are returned in the response. For this I have setup a filter. The filter is called (first log statement is working) but the logging of the headers is not working. I have this:

```
@Filter("/**")
public class MyFilter implements HttpFilter {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmountFilter.class);

@Override
public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
    request.getHeaders().forEach(h -> LOG.info("Headers sent are: {} <=> {}", h.getKey(), h.getValue()));
    Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> proceed = chain.proceed(request);
    proceed.subscribe(new Subscriber<HttpResponse<?>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(HttpResponse<?> resp) {
            resp.getHeaders().forEach(h -> LOG.debug("Header received: {} {}", h.getKey(), h.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }
    });
    return proceed;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems in your posted code

1. (lesser problem) Your filter does not implement `Ordered#getOrder`, so if another filter changes the headers of the HttpRespose, it is not guaranteed that this logging filter would capture the altered headers. To fix this, we can implement the `getOrder` method and make it return `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`, so that your logging filter will be first in the filter chain. then, the `chain.proceed()` call will call all of the other filters.
2. Using `Publisher` directly and/or manually implementing `Subscriber` is not really good practice. You can avoid doing so by using `Flowable.fromPublisher` (assuming you are using RxJava). This lets you use the much more ergonomic `Flowable` class and its `doOnNext` method. Additionally, the `proceed` publisher is getting subscribed to twice (once with your `Subscriber` implementation, and once by Micronaut to execute the request). Since `proceed` is a cold publisher (it only starts doing work once subscribed to), this causes the filter to execute the request twice, which raises an error with Micronaut.

By fixing these two problems, we get

```java
@Filter("/**")
public class MyFilter implements HttpFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFilter.class);

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
        request.getHeaders().forEach(h -> LOG.info("Headers sent are: {} <=> {}", h.getKey(), h.getValue()));

        Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> proceed = chain.proceed(request);

        return Flowable.fromPublisher(proceed)
                .doOnNext((resp) -> {
                    resp.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> LOG.debug("Header received: {} {}", key, value));
                });
    }

}
```

Finally, your first `LOG` statement is using `LOG.info`, while your second `LOG` statement is using `LOG.debug`. With the default `logback.xml` settings you will not be able to see any debug messages. To see **all** debug logs, you can

```xml
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```

to

```xml
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```

Alternatively, you can change the second statement to use `LOG.info` to avoid changing your `logback.xml` file.